# No input file specified - php

Tags: php, apache

I'm very new to php but worked a lot with javascript and html before. I'm hosting a server with apache on my own computer just for testing php. I installed php as cgi on it and everything worked fine. I did some testing with php just to get a feel for how it works, but when I tried to make a file upload form and read the file with php:

```
//uploadFile.php
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="uploadFile.php" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
            <input name="submit" value="upload" type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
            echo $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

I suddenly got the message:

> No input file specified

Only that! It didn't even said it was an error. I tried this very simple php script that worked before:

```
<?php
echo "Working";
?>
```

But I still got "No input file specified". Every php file I try gives me this error, wich indcates that the problem is't in my code. When I tried a normal .html file without php it worked. I have tried researching it and it seams like peaple hosting on godaddy gets this message, but I found no solution for me.

Do anyone know the solution or have any tips on how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: I love it when people change code after an answer has been given.

Comment: Thats just because I thought I was clear enough and that you would understand my problem, but you didn't, so I change to clearify things

Answer (score 1):

As per your [**originally posted code/question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26408923/1) where you changed your question after this answer has been submitted:

PHP is case sensitive when it comes to POST/FILES variables, or any variables for that matter.

You have `name="uploadfile"` and then `$_FILES["uploadFile"]`

Change it to `$_FILES["uploadfile"]`

`F` is not the same as `f`.

Or keep  `$_FILES["uploadFile"]`  and change `name="uploadfile"` to `name="uploadFile"`.

Either way, they both much match in letter-case.

---

Read the manual on uploading files:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php**

---

**Edit:** (example)

Sidenote:

Make sure the folder exists and has proper write permissions. You may need to adjust the way the `$uploads_dir = 'uploads';` is, depending on where you are executing the code from.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
            <input name="submit" value="upload" type="submit">
        </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$uploads_dir = 'uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["uploadFile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
  }

}

?>
    </body>

</html>
```

> *"When I tried a normal `.html` file without php it worked."*

Make sure that the code in my answer is used as a `.php` file and not `.html`.

You should also contact GoDaddy's technical support regarding this matter, and to see if PHP is indeed available for you to use.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: But I still get the same message for every php file

Comment: Since you're using all the code inside the same file, use `isset()` around `echo $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];` as in `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]; }` @Istlemin

Comment: @Istlemin Reload my answer, I've made an example edit. Make sure the folder exists and has proper write permissions. You may need to adjust the way the `$uploads_dir = 'uploads';` is, depending on where you are executing the code from.

Comment: @Istlemin Also make sure that the code in my answer is used as a `.php` file and not `.html`

Comment: As I just added to my question, every php file gives me this error, no matter what I put in in! It feels like you think the problem is in my file upload code. Sorry if my question was unclear

Comment: @Istlemin Which "error" exactly, "no input file specified"? I would contact GoDaddy/Tech support about this then. That doesn't make sense. I think it's a configuration issue somewhere, most likely `.htaccess` - have a look inside your error logs, there could be something in there.

Comment: @Istlemin I found a Q&A here on Stack that could help http://stackoverflow.com/q/14555996/ - Go over that entire page. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028471/

Comment: I think I clearly said I hosted it on my computer, not on goDaddy. And wich error logs? Apaches? I found no error there. And Where is the ..htaccess file?

Comment: @Istlemin Sorry about that, I thought you were hosted with that, apologies. Well, that's a different story. Firstly, is PHP indeed installed and properly configured?

Comment: @Istlemin Also make sure that the setting for uploading is enabled. I installed Wampserver last night on one of my machines and did notice a setting for it to that effect. As for log files, that will depend on the installation.